# Struggling to make algorithm to generate board for a puzzle game

Tags: c#, algorithm, puzzle

I'm looking to make a number puzzle game. For the sake of the question, let's say the board is a grid consisting of 4 x 4 squares. (In the actual puzzle game, this number will be 1..15)

A number may only occur once in each column and once in each row, a little like Sudoku, but without "squares".

Valid:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4
2, 3, 4, 1
3, 4, 1, 2
4, 1, 2, 3]
```

I can't seem to come up with an algorithm that will consistently generate valid, random n x n boards.

I'm writing this in C#.

Comment: You already solved it in the 4x4 case. As you can see, the solution is not random. Please precisely define what you mean by a random solution.

Answer (score 8):

Start by reading my series on graph colouring algorithms:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/

It is going to seem like this has nothing to do with your problem, but by the time you're done, you'll see that it has everything to do with your problem.

---

OK, now that you've read that, you know that you can use a graph colouring algorithm to *describe* a Sudoku-like puzzle and then solve a specific instance of the puzzle. But clearly you can use the same algorithm to *generate* puzzles.

Start by defining your graph regions that are fully connected.

Then modify the algorithm so that it tries to find *two* solutions.

Now create a blank graph and set one of the regions at random to a random colour. Try to solve the graph. Were there two solutions?  Then add another random colour. Try it again. Were there no solutions?  Then back up a step and add a different random colour.

Keep doing that -- adding random colours, backtracking when you get no solutions, and continuing until you get a puzzle that has a unique solution. And you're done; you've got a random puzzle generator.

Comment: That would work but this solution is hardly efficient. Wouldn't it take ages to generate 15x15 graphs this way?

Comment: Because it needs to find a solution in a huge problem space many times before it can return a unique-solution answer?

Comment: Unless I'm completely off-base in my calculations here, there are `1,710,012,252,724,199,424,000,000` unique solutions, and in the last step we're trying to find the only valid solution. That sounds complicated to me...

Answer (score 3):

It seems you could use this valid example as input to an algorithm that randomly swapped two rows a random number of times, then swapped two random columns a random number of times.

Comment: +1 Your solution is similar to mine (although you use a number of random swaps where I used one random permutation). But I think both yours and mine won't find all valid arrangements, see the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't too many combinations you need to try. You can always rearrange a valid board so the top row is 1,2,3,4 (by remapping the symbols), and the left column is 1,2,3,4 (by rearranging rows 2 thru 4). On each row there are only 6 permutations of the remaining 3 symbols, so you can loop over those to find which of the 216 possible boards are valid. You may as well store the valid ones.

Then pick a valid board randomly, randomly rearrange the rows, and randomly reassign the symbols.

Comment: Just noticed that you'd like it for n x n up to 15. That might be a bit tedious. :)

Comment: This would rapidly stop working for larger boards, he mentioned 4x4 in his example but didn't mention the actual size.

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak C#, but the following algorithm ought to be easily translated.

Associate a set consisting of the numbers 1..N with each row and column:

```
for i = 1 to N
  row_set[i] = column_set[i] = Set(1 .. N)
```

Then make a single pass through the matrix, choosing an entry for each position randomly from the set elements valid at that row and column.  Remove the number chosen from the respective row and column sets.

```
for r = 1 to N
  for c = 1 to N
    k = RandomChoice( Intersection( column_set[c], row_set[r] ))
    puzzle_board[r, c] = k
    column_set[c] = column_set[c] - k
    row_set[r] = row_set[r] - k
  next c
next r
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to generate uniformly distributed [Latin Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

This [pdf](http://designtheory.org/library/encyc/topics/mcrw.pdf) has a description of a method by Jacobson and Matthews (which was published elsewhere, a reference of which can be found here: http://designtheory.org/library/encyc/latinsq/z/)

Or you could potentially pre-generate a "lot" of them (before you ship :-)), store that in a file and randomly pick one.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be to create a partial game and solve it. If it's not solvable, or if it's wrong, make another. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sudoku without squares sounds a bit like Sudoku. :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/game/sudoku.aspx

There is an explanation of the board generator code they use there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/ - he's got several puzzles that have precisely this constraint (among others).

Answer (score 0):

Use your first valid example:

```
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

Then, create randomly 2 permutations of {1, 2, 3, 4}.

Use the first to permute rows and then the second to permute columns.

You can find several ways to create permutations in Knuth's [**The Art of Computer Programming (TAOCP)**](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html), Volume 4 Fascicle 2, Generating All Tuples and Permutations (2005), v+128pp. ISBN 0-201-85393-0.

If you can't find a copy in a library, a preprint (of the part that discusses permutations) is available at his site: [fasc2b.ps.gz](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc2b.ps.gz)

---

**EDIT - CORRECTION**

The above solution is similar to 500-Intenral Server Error's one. But I think both won't find all valid arrangements.

For example they'll find:

```
1 3 2 4 
3 1 4 2
2 4 1 3
4 2 3 1
```

but not this one:

```
1 2 3 4
2 1 4 3
3 4 1 2
4 3 2 1
```

One more step is needed: After rearranging rows and columns (either using my or 500's way), create one more permutation (lets call it `s3`) and use it to permute all the numbers in the array.

```
s3 = randomPermutation(1 ... n)
for i=1 to n
  for j=1 to n
    array[i,j] = s3( array[i,j] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A further solution would be this. Suppose you have a number of solutions. For each of them, you can generate a new solution by simply permuting the identifiers (1..15). These new solutions are of course logically the same, but to a player they will appear different.

The permutation might be done by treating each identifier in the initial solution as an index into an array, and then shuffling that array.